# Not getting expected results from MongoDB in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running NodeJS /w ExpressJS and MongoDB. I'm trying to create a very simple API but something is not working correctly. When I run `api.js` and go to `/api/media/movies` it gives me this output and not DB results. I know there are results in the database, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
  options: { },
  _conditions: {
    type: "Movie"
  },
  _updateArg: { },
  op: "find"
}
```

**api.js**

```
var app, express, models;

express = require('express');

models = require('./Librarian/models');

app = express();

app.get('/api/media/movies', function(req, res) {
  var movies;
  movies = models.Media.find({
    type: "Movie"
  });
  res.json(movies);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**./Librarian/models.js**

```
var Media, config, mongoose;

mongoose = require('mongoose');

config = require('../config');

mongoose.connect(config.mongo.connectString);

Media = mongoose.model('Media', {
  type: {
    type: String
  },
  path: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});

module.exports = {
  Media: Media
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot that I'm working in an async env. This works:

```
var app, express, models;

express = require('express');

models = require('./Librarian/models');

app = express();

app.get('/api/media/movies', function(req, res) {
  models.Media.find({
    type: "Movie"
  }, function(err, movies) {
    res.json(movies);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```